# What is the smallest page to show a tweet?

Tags: twitter, web-scraping

For scraping purposes, I'm trying to find the lightest way of getting the content of a tweet that would be present if it were embeded. For example, the following url: https://twitter.com/CNN/status/849245180356169728 has all the data that's behind, so weighs 203kb. However, I'm only interested in the following (everything in the "permalink-overlay" class):

[image]

Which is only 72.68 kb.

Is there not a URL somewhere that doesn't return everything in the background, or at least less?

P.S. Please don't direct me to https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed as I need to know stuff like the avatar of the user, if they are verified, and any linked media (video, photo, etc...), and I also can't run any javascript.

Comment: What environment / language are you using? Why not to make 2 separate requests: to get the content by the link https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FCNN%2Fstatus%2F849245180356169728 and to get user's data by the link https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=CNN ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the mobile version content by the link https://mobile.twitter.com/CNN/status/849245180356169728

Comment: This doesn't work, the mobile version loads it's data via the Twitter API after the page has been loaded.